# File upload causing unexpected token error in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'am trying to upload a file in angular. I'm getting HttpErrorResponse in my post request.

[image]

This is my service:

```
upploadFile(taskId, formData) {
  return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.getTask()}/upload/${taskId}`, formData);
}
```

And I am calling my service

```
const formData = new FormData();

this.uploadFile.forEach((file: File) => {
  formData.append('file', file);
})

this.taskService.upploadFile(taskId, formData)
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.onDestroy),
        finalize(() => this.isLoading = false),
        catchError(err => {
          this.isLoading = false;
          return throwError(err);
        })
      )
```

Is there anything wrong with my call in service?

Comment: Your BE is trying to parse it as a JSON Object whereas you are sending a File as body, it  probably should be solved on the BE side.

Comment: should it be possible to add responseType json?

Comment: It is not about the responseType but the request, Content-Type should be already present in your request but your BE is not handling it correctly.

Comment: I see. My backend is consuming applications/json value.

Comment: @raf,  the most possible is that you received an error page, not a Json, why? It's possible you has a CORS error, a error in your function or in your call

Comment: I receiver status 302. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @raf can you provide the console logs of the data that you are sending to the backend? because I'm thinking that you are trying to implement json.parse to the json element